# Primeng p-tree node drop to a droppable false node causes redirect in Firefox

Tags: angular, primeng

In Firefox, when a PrimeNg p-tree node dropped to droppable false node with in the same tree, browser initiate a redirect. "onNodeDrop" event not get hit in this case.

This happens only in Firefox. Other browsers works fine. 
Is there a way to solve this issue.
Or is this a know issue in primeng p-tree drag and drop?